# Select multiple columns with GROUP BY SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the min date value from one column, while grouping by another non-unique id column which has multiple duplicate values and also want to show the same rows that satisfy previous two conditions. The original database columns looks something like:

['TransactionDate','TransactionStatusID','DateOfEntry','DateOfService','Amount','TransactionTypeID','PaymentTypeId','PostDate','BillID','ChargeDetailID']

and 2nd table looks like:

['Amount', 'PracticeID', 'LoadDate', 'DateOfService', 'PerformingProvderID', 'CPTCodeID', 'ChargeDetailID']

I am joining these two tables on  "ChargeDetailID" like:

```
SELECT  cd.PatientID, MIN(t.DateOfService) AS "Date Of Service"
FROM ChargeDetail as cd inner join transactions as t on cd.ChargeDetailID = t.ChargeDetailID
WHERE cd.PatientID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cd.PatientID
```

Results that I get from this query:

```
|           PatientID|Date Of Service|
+--------------------+---------------+
|D37224C7-9157-4C5...|     2020-03-30|
|5E693AF8-8332-477...|     2014-01-07|
|8C071F5C-2210-4A6...|     2013-02-14|
|38B11DAE-3FF1-4AD...|     2012-03-14|
|7DB00C43-36F6-40E...|     2009-01-16|
|940EEC5C-4781-4EB...|     2016-12-08|
```

Results I want:

```
|           PatientID|Date Of Service|  cd.Amount| cd.BillID|
+--------------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|D37224C7-9157-4C5...|     2020-03-30|   500     |10009
|5E693AF8-8332-477...|     2014-01-07|   250     |1492
|8C071F5C-2210-4A6...|     2013-02-14|  350      |15892
|38B11DAE-3FF1-4AD...|     2012-03-14|  222      |15596
|7DB00C43-36F6-40E...|     2009-01-16|  899      |20566
|940EEC5C-4781-4EB...|     2016-12-08|  650      |9566
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windows function as below-

```
Select 
    PatientID
  , Amount
  , BillId
  , DateOfService As "Date Of Service"
from
 (SELECT  
     cd.PatientID
    ,cd.Amount
    ,cd.BillId
    ,t.DateOfService
    ,row_number() over(partition by cd.PatientID order by t.DateOfService asc) as seqnum
FROM ChargeDetail as cd inner join transactions as t 
on cd.ChargeDetailID = t.ChargeDetailID
WHERE cd.PatientID IS NOT NULL) t
Where t.seqnum = 1;
```

Note the MySQL & SqlServer are 2 different databases however the above approach should work for both.

Comment: Can we also add sum of amount where PatientID matches i tried this ` Select DateOfEntry, DateOfService, Amount, from  (SELECT t.DateOfEntry, t.DateOfService, sum(t.Amount) as TotalAmount FROM ChargeDetail as cd inner join transactions as t on cd.ChargeDetailID = t.ChargeDetailID WHERE cd.PatientID IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY PatientID `

Comment: Yup, we can. Since it’s a new requirement, I would suggest that you put a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add cd.amount and cd.billid in the group by. But requirement isnt much clear. You can use window functions too.

```
SELECT  cd.PatientID, cd.Amount, cd.BillID, MIN(t.DateOfService) AS "Date Of Service"
FROM ChargeDetail as cd inner join transactions as t on cd.ChargeDetailID = t.ChargeDetailID
WHERE cd.PatientID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cd.PatientID , cd.Amount, cd.BillID
```

Comment: but I want "cd.PatientID" to be unique. from that query there will be multiple enteries for  "cd.PatientID"

Comment: I wasnt ckear about requirement. You need to use window function like above answer.